# What tools can perform automatic relation extraction without any configuration or coding?

Tags: nlp

I have designed a system to do automatic relation extraction on a specific corpus, where the relations are not known in advance. I want to compare my system to another system that does [automatic relation extraction](http://reverb.cs.washington.edu/) to see if my system performs any better (for an academic thesis). The only such automatic extraction system that I know about is reverb.

In the readme for the [reverb](http://reverb.cs.washington.edu/) system they say that reverb is "is designed for Web-scale information extraction, where the target relations cannot be specified in advance and speed is important." My system is much slower than reverb (I think because it parses sentences and performs deeper analysis) so I am not sure if the comparison is meaningful. I extract more relations but the comparison is a little unfair (because my system is so much more computationally intensive). Are there other systems like reverb that can do automatic relation extraction? Maybe systems that are not "designed for web-scale information extraction" that are more fair competitors?

I know NLTK does relation extraction but you have to supply a specific regex glue to bind entities in a relation.

Are there other tools out there that NLP practitioners use to do automatic relation extraction?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's what you need, but both AlchemyAPI and OpenCalais have some sort of relation extraction and they both claim it's "generic". Here are two links: OpenCalais: http://www.opencalais.com/documentation/opencalais-web-service-api/api-metadata-english/generic-relation-extraction AlchemyAPI: http://www.alchemyapi.com/products/features/relation-extraction/ . They both have public demos and available web services.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the NLP research world, extracting relations without specifying which relations you are looking for is called "open relation extraction."

There are a few leading systems for performing "open relation extraction", some of which are available "out of the box"

- [Reverb](http://reverb.cs.washington.edu/) from the University of Washington runs on input text and outputs relations
- [PATTY](https://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/departments/databases-and-information-systems/research/yago-naga/patty/) from the Max Planck Institute provides a large set of relations extracted from The New York Times and Wikipedia from a big experiment. You can download the relations  (see "Downloads" section in link) -- then grep for them in your corpus. Note that some of the relations have part of speech tags included, so to match those relations you need to find the parts of speech in your corpus (using some tagger like NLTK) and then see if they match the textual patterns from PATTY.
- [Exemplar](https://github.com/U-Alberta/exemplar/) from the University of Alberta.

The paper "Effectiveness and Efficiency of Open Relation Extraction" by Filipe Mesquita surveys some of the cutting-edge relation extraction systems as of fall 2013.